# Viewport affecting relative position of a nested element in resizable div

Tags: javascript, html, css, vue.js, openlayers

In [this app I made](https://eccc-msc.github.io/msc-animet/?layers=RADAR_1KM_RRAI,CURRENT_CONDITIONS,RADAR_COVERAGE_RRAI,RADAR_COVERAGE_RRAI.INV&extent=-8065890,5016498,-6514843,6093524&mapwh=962,668), where I use Vue and OpenLayers to create animations, a `img` element with `position: relative` is placed at the top right corner of a `canvas` element with `resize: both; overflow: auto;`. The problem ([CodePen](https://codepen.io/StuckDuckF/pen/mdLoRew)) is said element is used to create an animation in a for loop where at each iteration the `canvas` element is used as a frame after updated and rendered. At each step the `canvas` element is sued to compose a new canvas and another `img` tag (same as the one overlaying the `canvas` but hidden to overcome some Vue and OpenLayers particularities) is `.getElementById(...)` and `.getContext("2d").drawImage(...)` onto the frame `canvas`. For some weird `viewport` related reason the `img` element tends to drift to the middle of the `canvas` element when the viewport is resized or on a multi-monitor (uncommon aspect ratios also trigger it) setup even though before the loop starts composing the `canvas` frames it freezes the dimensions of all the elements so that size of the output is consistent with the initial frame.

My question is what could be affecting the widths I used to calculate where the `img` element should be (see JS code below) that is related to multi-screen setup, `viewport` or other but works 100% on more regular setups?

```js
if (showLegendFlag === true) {
  const mapLegend = document.getElementById("mapLegend");
  mapCnv
    .getContext("2d")
    .drawImage(
      mapLegend,
      mapCnv.width - mapLegend.width,
      0,
      mapLegend.width,
      mapLegend.height
    ); // drawImage(image, dx, dy, dWidth, dHeight)
}
```

```html
<div id="map" class="map">
  <img id="legendMapOverlay" src="https://geo.weather.gc.ca/geomet?version=1.3.0&service=WMS&request=GetLegendGraphic&sld_version=1.1.0&layer=GDPS.CONV_KINDEX.PT3H&format=image/png&STYLE=KINDEX&lang=en"/>
</div>

<img id="mapLegend" :src="mapLegendURL" style="display: none;" v-if="displayMapLegend" crossorigin="anonymous" />
```

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

OpenLayers may have a transform set on the canvas depending on the device pixel ratio.  You could try two options:

**Option 1**
Specify `pixelRatio: 1,` in the `ol.Map` options to override the device pixel ratio so no transform is needed.

**Option 2**
Reset the transform before you draw the image, but surround the calls with `save()` and `restore()`

```
  const mapCtx = mapCnv.getContext("2d")
  mapCtx.save();
  mapCtx.resetTransform()
  mapCtx
    .drawImage(
      mapLegend,
      mapCnv.width - mapLegend.width,
      0,
      mapLegend.width,
      mapLegend.height
    );
  mapCtx.restore();
```

Note that OpenLayers version 6 and 7 do not have a single map canvas and your approach might not work.

Comment: The `pixelratio` solution worked for me, but why would it affect only certain machines with same setups (Chrome Windows 10 on 1080p monitors)?

Comment: Most likely the display resolution in the Windows settings is different to the device resolution, or page zoom is not 100% in the browser's appearance settings.